# Calculating column in datagridview

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a form and I'm wondering is it possible to calculate a specific column in a datagridview and output it to a label with the use of a generate button? If yes how do I go about doing it?

Thanks

(this is how the datagridview is set up)

```
Private Sub refreshdata()
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'open connection
            cnn.Open()
        End If
        'create new data and insert the data, Employee, Firstname, lastname, address etc.
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT employeeno as [EmployeeID], " & _
                                        "firstname as [FirstName], lastname as [LastName], address as [Address], department as [Department], workinghours as [WorkingHours], datehired as [DateHired], contactnumber as [ContactNumber] " & _
                                        "FROM employee ORDER BY EmployeeNo", cnn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        'fill data into datatable
        da.Fill(dt)
        'offer data to be placed in datagridview
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        'close connection
        cnn.Close()
    End Sub`enter code here`
```

Comment: What do you mean by output specific column to a label? Just header text or all data from the specific column with specific string format?

Comment: yes or a text box if possible

Comment: yes it is possible.  how: write some code to walk thru the rows and calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do. If you want just column header in your textBox try this:

**C#**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].HeaderText;
}
```

**VB**

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Columns("columnName").HeaderText
End Sub
```

To place your output inside label simply change `textBox1.Text` to `label1.Text`. If you want all data written inside your cells of certain column try this:

**C#**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow)
            break;

        sb.Append(row.Cells["columnName"].Value + " ");
    }

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

**VB**

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then
            Exit For
        End If

        sb.Append(row.Cells("columnName").Value + " ")
    Next

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

By the way, column name is the column name in design when you right click your `DataGridView` > *Edit columns* under design, there should be a *"Name"* parameter. Hopefully this covers the answer for your question. Cheers!

**EDIT:**

Added total sum of column output in textBox solution:

**C#**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow)
            break;

        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(row.Cells["columnName"].Value.ToString(), out number))
            sum += number;
    }

    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

**VB**

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then
            Exit For
        End If

        Dim number As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("columnName").Value.ToString(), number) Then
            sum += number
        End If
    Next

    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to let you know, I created my data in datagridview using SQL and did not just import database, does that make a difference because I used your code and it doesn't work :(

Comment: @user3562155 how do you load date into your datagridview? post some code or pictures, I'm not sure what you're doing..

Comment: @user3562155 Your DataGridView fills just fine with your data right? If that's so, lets say you want to place all first names in your text box. All you have to do is to change sb.Append(row.Cells("columnName").Value + " ") -> "columnName" to "FirstName" inside your brackets. I just made the whole DataGridView with data table to try it out and it works. Do you get any error or something?

Comment: hi, yes it works, it displays all the numbers into the text box, but what I want is it to calculate the numbers by adding and giving me a total, how would i do this?

Comment: @user3562155 I updated my answer in "EDIT:" section. It should solve your problem.